# setTimeout() firing prematurely when showing an alert() in Chrome

Tags: javascript, webkit, settimeout, alert, confirm

I have the following code:

```
t = setTimeout(function () { blah();  }, 900000);
```

Which, basically, calls blah after 15 minutes of the page having loaded.

However, if at some point I show an alert() or a confirm(), then as soon as it is dismissed, blah() gets executed for some reason.

As far as I've seen, this only happens in Safari/Chrome. It doesn't happen in IE/Firefox.

Any ideas what's going on, or even better, how to solve this?

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Are you sure that the `blah` is called from the function set with `setTimeout`? Might be it is called somewhere else.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me. Maybe create a small page which you can reproduce this error and let us try?

Comment: Note you can feed setTimeout the `blah` function directly: `setTimeout(blah, 900000)`.

Comment: @vsr: blah is *only* called from within the setTimeout, and from nowhere else

Comment: @muratgu: I haven't been able to reproduce it with a small page that only does this either, but I can't find what kind of interference I have here either...

Comment: @Dykam, sure. It doesn't fix the problem, though...

Comment: You are not alone, this is the bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43796

Comment: @Daniel Magliola, not saying it fixes the bug, just pointing you at a better syntax ;)

Comment: @vsr: Thank you very much for finding that! Could you place that as an answer so I can give you the points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not alone, this is the bug: [code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43796](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43796)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has not been solved by the chromium team.

I found that, by introducing some delay between clearTimeout and the setTimeout, will solve the problem.

```
// mouse event
document.onmousemove = function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  debug("Idle Timer reinitialized"); // apparently this function introduces some delay. it just works. You may want to include another timer here like for 2-3 seconds.
  timeout = setTimeout(logoutNow, systemTimeout);
}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the cause, I ran this demo and can not replicate it.

"Timeout!" will appear after 10 seconds, click in the box before hand to test.

http://jsfiddle.net/PFgaJ/

Comment: I've looked at this code as hard as I can, and I can't find any other reason. I'm showing a certain dialog when that timeout expires, and the dialog shows up when I dismiss the dialog. I'm ONLY showing that dialog from within this function, and that function is ONLY called from the setTimeout, so I can't really find another explanation.

Comment: @Daniel Magliola If it's not reproducible then it will be hard, have you tried the same page on other machines to rule out a local issue?